# How to create a PageReference (url) to approval history?

Tags: visualforce, url, pagereference

I have a visualforce button that submits an approval request. I would like the method to return a PageReference that brings the user to the full Approval History related list. I can't seem to figure out how to do that without hardcoding the url.

Here is my code:

```
return new ApexPages.StandardController(theOpportunity).view();
```

It returns a url like this:

```
https://mydomain--staging.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Opportunity/0063z000014zQWVAA2/view
```

I want it to return this:

```
https://mydomain--staging.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Opportunity/0063z000014zQWVAA2/related/ProcessSteps/view
```

Comment: You'll likely need to get creative for two reasons: there's no guarantee the object of the record you're clicking on has any approval processes and there also is no guarantee that it has any associated approval history. Check out [Lightning Experience Page References](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm) where there is a navigation event to navigate to a record's related list.

Comment: I do already check whether there is an open approval process, as follows. Because my VisualForce page is used to submit an approval process, and it will refuse if there is already one pending.

Comment: SELECT Id, ProcessDefinition.Name 
FROM ProcessInstance 
WHERE TargetObject.id = :theOpportunity.Id
AND CompletedDate = null

Comment: I hesitated to hard code URL, but given the resource that @nbrown referenced, I am using the following code, which does what I want.

Comment: return new Pagereference('/lightning/r/Opportunity/%/related/ProcessSteps/view'.replace('%', theOpportunity.Id));

Answer (score 0):

```java
return new Pagereference('/lightning/r/Opportunity/%/related/ProcessSteps/view'
    .replace('%', theOpportunity.Id));
```